# Access a JSON response using jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, json, flask

I have a JSON response returning from a flask(python) server.

```
     response = make_response(json.dumps({top_tag:text}))
     return response
```

top_tag is an HTML tag
text is some HTML text

I want to use my done function to get both items from the JSON

```
     .done(function (data, status, jqXHR) {     
        $('section:not([class])').html(data);
```

But instead of the above code I want to put the 'text' into the top_tag on my web page.
Because of what I am doing the top_tag is going to vary.

So i want to extract an HTML tag (top_tag) from my response find that tag on my web page and then insert my text into that tag.

Thinking about it it doesnt have to be JSON. If someone knows a way to return a variable and text from a flask app and then do the above I'm all ears.

Thanks
(hope thats clear)

Comment: what's top_tag? an id/class for the html elm ?

Comment: The top_tag will change depending on the page. Sometimes it will just be a tag, sometimes it will be a div with an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

The Flask side:

```
 response = jsonify({'tag': top_tag, 'text': text})
 return response
```

The jQuery side:

```
 .done(function (data, status, jqXHR) {     
    $(data.tag).html(data.text);
 }
```

Comment: Talk about being too close to it. Feel like an idiot right now.
Cheers Miguel

Comment: `Flask` already have `jsonify` so you code can be simplified `return jsonify({'tag': top_tag, 'text': text})`.

Comment: @tbicr: sure, I have updated my answer to show the shorter form.